# c++ MFC converting a string in an edit control to hexidecimal

Tags: c++, string, mfc, hex, cedit

I can convert strings to hex perfectly fine if I define them in the source for example:

```
int input = 15;
CString output;
output.Format(L"%x", input);
m_oput.SetWindowText(output);
```

The result is 'f', but how come if I do this:

```
TCHAR buffer[500];
int input = GetDlgItemText(TOCON, buffer, 50);
CString output;
output.Format(L"%x", input);
m_oput.SetWindowText(output);
```

The output is '2'? I have tried a few other ways of getting text from the edit control, but each of them have returned the wrong results. Is there something wrong with how I am getting text from the control in general, or what I have set for maxcount?

Comment: GetDlgItemText returns number of characters read from dialog control, not the text itself; so it is logical that output is 2. And text itself appears in `buffer` variable in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetDlgItemText` copies the text form the edit control into buffer and returns the number of characters read from dialog control, **not** the text interpreted as a number. The way to go is to first convert the string in `buffer` to an integer and then supply this to `output.Format`. For example, you can do this with the function `atoi`. Your modified code would look like this:

```
TCHAR buffer[500];
GetDlgItemText(TOCON, buffer, 50);
int input = atoi(buffer);
CString output;
output.Format(L"%x", input);
m_oput.SetWindowText(output);
```

Comment: Super! If it works then please select this as the correct answer.

Comment: Just waiting for the time limit to expire before I can accept as answer.

Comment: Ahhh! Just learnt from you that there is a time limit on accepting an answer. You learn something new each day!